# Is there a way to deploy flutter app on Google play console instead of Google Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I want to test the app as beta version but i don't want to deploy it on Google Play Store yet. I found that Google Play Console is the equavelant of IOS's Testflight. I couldn't find a way to deploy the app on Google Play Console. Is the process the same with Google Play Store deployment or is there another way?

Comment: You can publish your app in testing mode.

Answer (score 1):

For these conditions, you can actually do a internal testing.
That way you don't have to publish the app but you can test it normally also share with testers

[Internal Testing in Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/)